# How to roll back by one day?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am looking for the solution for the one day back if the count is 0.
or if there is any way to do this by the query then that will we more useful.

```
exports.getYesterdayCount = (req, res) => {
  const { id} = req.body;
  const date = new Date();
  let yesterday = ((d) => new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1)))(new Date());

  money.findAll({
    where: {
      my_id: id,
    },
  }).then((moneyData) => {
    const storeId = moneyData[0].dataValues.mynew_ids;

    Store.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
        store_id: storeId,
        date: yesterday,
        entry_or_exit: "Entry",
        customer_or_employee: "Customer",
      },
    }).then((yesterdayStoreCount) => {
    if (yesterdayStoreCount === 0) {
      //here i want if yesterdayStoreCount === 0 then go one day back
    }

      const yestardayCountObj = {
        yesterdayCount: "",
      };
      yestardayCountObj.yesterdayCount = yesterdayStoreCount.count;
      res.send(yestardayCountObj);
    });
  });
};
```

tried writing a recursive function but facing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out a record with a maximum date before today and then execute a query by that date.

```
const previousDate = await Store.max('date', {
      where: {
        store_id: storeId,
        date: {
          [Op.lt]: todayDate
        },
        entry_or_exit: "Entry",
        customer_or_employee: "Customer",
      },
    })
const result = await Store.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
        store_id: storeId,
        date: previousDate,
        entry_or_exit: "Entry",
        customer_or_employee: "Customer",
      },
    })
```